# separate gawk header by column

Tags: gawk

I am trying to separate a header into 3 fields using `gawk` and can not seem to get the desired result: `$1` is the target column, `$2` is the Gene|GC column, and `$3` is the Average column.

**gawk**

```
gawk  '{sub(/-[0-9]+/,"",$2); ar[$2]=$0}
        END{n = asort(ar)
                 printf "%-8s%8s%8s\n", "Target", "Gene|GC", "Average Depth" 
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                 print ar[i]}' OFS='\t' file
```

**input**

```
 chr2:198299650-198299769 SF3B1-823|gc=51.3 143.1
 chr17:42153038-42153421 G6PC3-1981|gc=61.6 406.7
 chr13:32903545-32903664 BRCA2-318|gc=27.7 39.6
 chr17:56811469-56811593 RAD51C-2465|gc=44.4 228.5
```

**current output**

```
TargetGene|GCAverage Depth
chr10:79793602-79793721 RPS24|gc=59.7   150.3
chr10:79795083-79795202 RPS24|gc=41.2   111.4
chr10:79797665-79797784 RPS24|gc=37 69.8
chr10:79799902-79800021 RPS24|gc=39.5   134.5
```

**desired output**

```
Target                  Gene|GC         Average Depth
chr10:79793602-79793721 RPS24|gc=59.7   150.3
chr10:79795083-79795202 RPS24|gc=41.2   111.4
chr10:79797665-79797784 RPS24|gc=37 69.8
```

Comment: we have no idea what your input file looks like. Please add just the sample data needed to get your desired output. Good luck.

Comment: I added an example input and though the actual output is different from the input the format is always the same.  It is always 3 fiels that are used to produce the output.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like all I needed was:

```
gawk  '{sub(/-[0-9]+/,"",$2); ar[$2]=$0}
        END{n = asort(ar)
                 print "Target","Gene|GC","Average Depth"
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                 print ar[i]}' OFS='\t' file
```

not sure if it is the best way, but the output is fine.  Thank you :).